# Capturing Single Click and Double Click events

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I need to capture both single and double click events using the Google Maps API. I'm capturing both at the moment but the single click is also running when a double click occurs which I can understand as a double click = 2 single clicks.

I'd like to disable the single click event if a double click event occurs but not sure how or if this is possible.

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
  console.log("single click");
});


google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dblclick', function(event) {
  console.log("double click");
});
```

At the moment I get both log entries when I double click - I'm hoping there's a way to determine that a double click has occurred and disable the single click event at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple workaround: remove the dblclick listener and use a timer.. Here is [an example](https://www.hhutzler.de/blog/handling-double-click-events-on-markers-in-google-maps-js-api-v3/) that uses the same logic for single/double click on a map marker (tMarker), modify the code to fit your need:

```js
 google.maps.event.addListener(tMarker, "click", function (e) 
    {
        var closureTrackID = tid;
  
        handleClickONMarker(closureTrackID);
        return false;       
    });
   

function doDoubleClickProcessing(closureTrackID)
{
    logMessage("mySlider.js::doDoubleClickProcessing -:: trackID:  " + closureTrackID);
    doSingleClickProcessing(closureTrackID);    
}

var singleClickInProgess = false;
var clickTimeout = 300;
function handleClickONMarker(tid)
{
    if ( singleClickInProgess )
    {
        logStatus("slider.js::handleClickONMarker:: DOUBLE CLICK trackID: " + tid);
        singleClickInProgess = false;
        doDoubleClickProcessing(tid);
    } 
    else
    {
        singleClickInProgess = true;
        setTimeout(checkClickONMarkerStatus,300,tid);
    }       
}

function checkClickONMarkerStatus(tid)
{
    if ( singleClickInProgess  )
    {
        singleClickInProgess = false;
        logStatus("slider.js::handleClickONMarker:: SINGLE CLICK trackID: " + tid);
        doMarkerProcessing( tid)   
     }
    singleClickInProgess = false;
}
```